# how to pass decimal to CasperJS via CLI?

Tags: javascript, casperjs

Here is my code:

```
var casper = require('casper').create({
});
var D = casper.cli.get(0);
casper.echo(D);   

casper.run();
```

and when i run it:

```
G:\GG\casperjs-1.1.3\bin>casperjs 3.js 100.00
100

G:\GG\casperjs-1.1.3\bin>
```

I showed 100 but not 100.00.
What's wrong with it?
How can I pass decimal to CasperJS via CLI?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try in your browser console the following code:

```
var d = 100.00;
console.log(d);
```

Your browser will display : 100

But if you try this :

```
var d = 100.05;
console.log(d);
```

Your browser will display : 100.05

And if you try this :

```
var d = 100.00;
console.log(d.toFixed(2));
```

Your browser will display : 100.00